# Making Span tag cover entire width of button

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="top">
  <button class="wrap">
    <span class="text">Hello</span>
  </button>
 </div>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
.top{
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 216px;
  height: 70px;
}

.wrap, .text{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have seen several posts regarding the "span taking the entire width of their parent" and the most popular answer was to make it `display: block;`

But in this case, it doesn't work. If you inspect, you will see that the span is taking 200px width instead of 216px width (width of button).

How can I fix this problem? Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShellZero/3qz3qrdg/15/)

Comment: Try setting the padding on your button to zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is padding in your .wrap class.  Set padding to 0 on your .wrap, .text declaration.

```
.top {
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 216px;
  height: 70px;
}

.wrap, .text {
  padding: 0px;  //set padding to 0px
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I just figured out the answer too by looking at the computed styles! I was about to post my answer but you were fast! Thanks a lot :)